# how to monitor AWS-RDS vis prometheus using cloudwatch exporter

Tags: prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, exporter

cloud watch exporter link- https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter

how to config deathwatch exporter in Prometheus .

can you guide me the steps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve RDS monitoring, you would need to use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/installation/debian/) for it. You would need the IAM user as well with AWS managed policy “CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess”.

1. Create an IAM user on the AWS panel with progammatic access only, attach the managed policy “CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess”, and and generate the access key and secret access.
2. Add CloudWatch as the data source to Grafana, with the name “CloudWatch” (the pre-defined graphs rely on this name), and choose any region. In the Authentication Provider section, choose "Access & secret key", and enter the information in the below tab for "Access Key ID" and "Secret Access Key" and then save & test.
3. Import the dashboard JSON file to enter dashboard id “702” in the “Grafana.com Dashboard” field of the importing form in Grafana and Load it, You are done.